# How to pass variable value in CAML query?

Tags: caml, query

[image]

I have a Dropdown list, I want to pass selected value of this dropdown to caml query. Please suggest solutions for this SharePoint online query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query below :

```
var queryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/><Value Type='Choice'>" + sel + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: @SPUser2017 Please don't forget to accept the correct answer in case it helped you!